# Google Nexus 4 Battery icon does not appear while charging

Tags: nexus-4, google, notification-led, lg

It so happened that my **LG google nexus 4** was *water damaged*.
I kept it under a bulb to dry the water for 1 day
Next day I took it to LG service center, he opened the phone and *removed the water* and asked me to charge the phone for 5 hours.
I connected the phone to power cable. RED LED light kept on blinking for all 5 hours and I thought it was charging.
Then I disconnected and tried to charge it on but it did not work.
I disconnected from power pressed and hold volume control button and power button and connected the power.
I kept holding on for almost an hour.
Then I left it to charge.
Still I do not see the battery icon.But the **RED LED stopped**, now there is no LEDs blinking or on!! Does this mean that the battery is charging? What next Should I do.
The service center guy told me if it does not boot up, he needs to replace the motherboard and the connector. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the phone in [rice](http://lifehacker.com/269427/dry-out-your-soaked-gadgets-in-rice) for the next 48 hours minimum before sending it away. That seems to be the trick as the phone is quite tight, and certain components may need more time before the moisture will evaporate. Having opened a Nexus 4 myself, I can attest to how tightly the plastic seals.

Comment: Leaving in rice! does it really work?

Comment: The service center guy has removed the moisture, so no question of leaving in rice, I want to know if there is a way to turn on the phone now and stop the blinking red light?